# ReactJS: Return API results on new page

Tags: reactjs, api, redirect, routes

I'm building a job board and making a simple jobs api request on my homepage.

Once a job search and location is entered in my form, my results successfully are mapped through and appear on the same page.

Let's say I want the job results to appear, on a new page url, on submit, can I do this still in the front end of my ReactJS api?

Or do I need to use REST routing?  And if so, does that mean I need to make my api call in the backend as well?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you include the code you have written so far? Are you using [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy)?

Comment: @Tholle - Sure here's a link to CodeSandBox.  Just search for 'developer' (jobs) in 'london':  https://codesandbox.io/s/34kzz5k6k1

Comment: [React Router might fit your use case](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic).

Comment: @Tholle - ok thank you, I'll give 'Modal Gallery' ago.  https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery . If anyone has any other suggestions too, that would be great. thank you.

Comment: Use react-router for front-end routing.  You can pass state from your current page to the new route in the `<Link />` component - the docs are good and this is essentially the standard for front-end routing in React.  Don't use REST routing on a SPA.

Comment: @jsw324 thank you JSW324.  Quick question - what is a SPA?  Single page application?

Comment: @ReenaVerma yes.